# What can I do to fix my simple computer-player game code? Syntax Error

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I wanted to practice doing loops because I’ve been having the most trouble with them. I decided to make a game where the user will pick a number from 0-100 to see if they can win against the computer.
What I have going right now is only the beginning. The code isn’t finished. But trying out the code I got a Syntax error where the arrow pointed at the colon on the `elif` function. 
How do I fix this? What can I do? 
I accept any other additional comments on my code to make it better.

Here’s my code:

```
import random
min = 0
max = 100
roll_again = "yes"
quit = "no"
players_choice = input()
computer = random.randint
while roll_again == "yes":
print("Pick a number between 1-100: ")
print(players_choice)
if players_choice >= 0:
print("Your number of choice was: ")
print(players_choice)
print("Your number is high.")
if computer >= 0:
print("Computers number is: ")
print(computer)
print("Computers number is high.")
if computer >= players_choice:
print("Computer wins.")
print("You lose.")
print("Would you like to play again? ", +roll_again)
elif: 
print(quit)
end
```

Goal:

Fix computer-player game while learning more about python. Providing additional documentation on where to start would be helpful.

Comment: if this is exactly what you have you need to add/correct indentation blocks (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html))

Comment: You presumably meant `else` rather than `elif`.

Comment: Also what is `end`?

Comment: Can you further describe what you want to achieve in the last few lines? i.e., how do you want the program to determine whether to play again? Because `print("Would you like to play again? ", + roll_again)` just prints "Would you like to play again? yes" and the loop continues indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error pointing to `elif` is because `elif` needs a condition to check. You need to use `if` `elif` and `else` like this:

```
if a == b:
    print('A equals B!')
elif a == c:
    print('A equals C!')
else:
   print('A equals nothing...')
```

Also, Python relies on indentation to determine what belongs to what, so make sure you are paying attention to your indents (there is no `end`).

Your code has more errors after you fix the if statements and indentation, but you should be able to look up help to fix those.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of indentiation issues and the `if` and `elif` statements are used incorrectly. Also take a look at how while loops work.

Based on the code you provided here is a working solution, but there are many other ways to implement this.

Here is some helpful tutorials for you on `if/else` statements as well as other beginner topics:

[Python IF...ELIF...ELSE Statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else)

```
import random
minval = 0
maxval = 100
roll_again = "yes"
quit_string = "no"

while True:
    players_choice = int(input("Pick a number between 1-100:\n"))
    computer = random.randint(minval,maxval)

    #checks if players choice is between 0 and 100
    if players_choice >= 0 and players_choice <= 100:
        print("Your number of choice was: ")
        print(players_choice)
    #otherwise it is out of range
    else:
        print("Number out of range")
    #check if computers random number is in range from 0 to 100        
    if computer >= 0 and computer <= 100:
        print("Computers number is: ")
        print(computer)
    # if computer's number is greater than players number, computer wins   
    if computer > players_choice:
        print("Computer wins.")
        print("You lose.")
    #otherwise if players number is higher than computers, you win
    elif computer < players_choice:
        print("You won.")
    #if neither condition is true, it is a tie game
    else:
        print("Tied game")

    #ask user if they want to continue        
    play_choice = input("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no\n")
    #checks text for yes or no use lower method to make sure if they type uppercase it matches string from roll_again or quit_string 
    if play_choice.lower() == roll_again:
        #restarts loop
        continue
    elif play_choice.lower() == quit_string:
        #breaks out of loop-game over
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code. Here is a working version, hope it helps you understand some of the concepts.
If not, feel free to ask

```
import random

# min and max are names for functions in python. It is better to avoid using
# them for variables
min_value = 0
max_value = 100

# This will loop forever uless something 'breaks' the loop
while True:
  # input will print the question, wait for an anwer and put it in the
  # 'player' variable (as a string, not a number)
  player = input("Pick a number between 1-100: ")

  # convert input to a number so we can compare it to the computer's value
  player = int(player)

  # randint is a function (it needs parentheses to work)
  computer = random.randint(min_value, max_value)

  # print what player and computer chose
  print("Your choice: ", player)
  print("Computer's choice: ", computer)

  # display the results
  if computer >= player:
    print("Computer wins. You loose")
  else:
    print("you win.")

  # Determine if user wants to continue playing
  choice = raw_input("Would you like to play again? (yes/No) ")
  if choice != 'yes':
    # if not
    break
```